# MongoDB : Application generated _id containing country and sequence as shard key?

Tags: mongodb, hash, key, sharding

I have some very basic questions regarding shard key.

In our application, we are creating _id fields from a coarse grained attribute -country and a **per country** monotonically increasing sequence number eg IN_1. As per several online references and books (eg http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/01/04/how-to-choose-a-shard-key-the-card-game/), it is better to have a compound shard key - coarse grained key + search key. We also have a country attribute in the shard key and have an index on that.

Most, if not all of our queries on these collections are going to be country search based or _id based.

What would be the best choice for a shard key

1. just _id - since ctry is already baked into it - will it make
   queries starting with ctry slow?
2. {ctry: 1, _id: 1} - but part of my _id is monotonically increasing sequence.
3. {ctry: 1, _id: hashed} - Promises both read locality and write distribution. Is this supported by MongoDB?
4. just {_id: hashed} - will it make queries starting with ctry slow?

I am inclined to using the option 3- but is that possible - it is not very clear from MongoDB docs.

Answer (score 1):

> just _id - since ctry is already baked into it - will it make queries starting with ctry slow?

I don't recommend this. `_id` is monotonically increasing so it will concentrate writes on a single shard. If you are also doing queries with the shape

```
{ "ctry" : "United States" }
```

then they will be broadcast to all shards, not targeted.

> {ctry: 1, _id: 1} - but part of my _id is monotonically increasing sequence.

`_id` is monotonically increasing but, as long as you are inserting documents with shard key values containing different values for `ctry`, the shard key values are not monotonically increasing, so you will not be concentrating writes on a single shard. However, for a given country `c`, all writes will go to only one of the shards containing chunks with `ctry = c`.

This seems reasonable.

> {ctry: 1, _id: hashed} - Promises both read locality and write distribution. Is this supported by MongoDB?

I like this best. It supports your queries, provides read isolation, and spreads out writes. Hashed shard keys in MongoDB are built on a single field, but you can compute your own hash `hashed_id` and store that on the document, then shard on

```
{ "ctry" : 1, "hashed_id" : 1 }
```

> just {_id: hashed} - will it make queries starting with ctry slow?

The monotonicity problem is gone but `ctry` queries will still be scatter-gather.